# Particle system dissapears on start

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have a particle system that dissapears from the hierachy when the game starts. Its not set to play on awake and its not set to destroy when finished. There is also no code that targets it other than to call its start method. [image]

Following is the only code that targets the particle:

```
       ParticleSystem[] Fx;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Fx = GetComponentsInChildren<ParticleSystem> ();
        MessageHub.Subscribe ( MessageTopics.DisplayUI_FX_string, DisplayFx );
    }

    public void DisplayFx( Message displayFxMessage )
    {
        var fxName = displayFxMessage.Open<string> ();
        PlayFx ( fxName );
    }

    void PlayFx( string name )
    {
        var fx = Fx.FirstOrDefault ( f => f.name == name );
        if ( fx == null )
        {
            Debug.LogError ( $"UI FX not found! There is no UI FX called {name}" );
            return;
        }

        fx.Play ();

    }
```

Comment: Could a script be targeting any of its hierarchy parent elements, or searching through a parent element's children for particle systems? If you take it out of its current hierarchy position, does it still disappear?

Comment: do you have anything that might  get hit by a particle and destroy it?

Comment: Uff sorry. I realised I was using a free aset from the store and it actually had a script that destroyed it.